# how to avoid if/else loops in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

The below code works perfectly but the if/else statements look so long and ugly. Is there a way I can avoid these statements?

`CommissionTypeFilterVm` is a list that contains 6 properties shown below whose values are either `1` or `0`. I wanted to enable and disable the checkbox's based on the values of these properties:

```
CommissionType
CommissionTrials
OverrideType
OverrideTrials
BonusType
AdjustmentType
```

Here is the code:

```
   if (view != null) 
        {
            if (view.CommissionTypeFilterVm !=null && view.CommissionTypeFilterVm.length>0)
            {
                if (view.CommissionTypeFilterVm[0].CommissionType != 1) {
                    this.$commissionType.prop("checked", false).prop("disabled", true);
                } else {
                    this.$commissionType.prop("disabled", false).prop("checked", true);
                }
                if (view.CommissionTypeFilterVm[0].CommissionTrials != 1) {
                    this.$commissionTrails.prop("checked", false).prop("disabled", true);
                } else {
                    this.$commissionTrails.prop("disabled", false).prop("checked", true);
                }
                if (view.CommissionTypeFilterVm[0].OverrideType != 1) {
                    this.$overrideType.prop("checked", false).prop("disabled", true);
                } else {
                    this.$overrideType.prop("disabled", false).prop("checked", true);
                }
                if (view.CommissionTypeFilterVm[0].OverrideTrials != 1) {
                    this.$overrideTrails.prop("checked", false).prop("disabled", true);
                } else {
                    this.$overrideTrails.prop("disabled", false).prop("checked", true);
                }
                if (view.CommissionTypeFilterVm[0].BonusType != 1) {
                    this.$bonusType.prop("checked", false).prop("disabled", true);
                } else {
                    this.$bonusType.prop("disabled", false).prop("checked", true);
                }
                if (view.CommissionTypeFilterVm[0].AdjustmentType != 1) {
                    this.$adjustmentType.prop("checked", false).prop("disabled", true);
                } else {
                    this.$adjustmentType.prop("disabled", false).prop("checked", true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This would be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Depending on what else is contained in `view`, you could use a for in loop to loop through all properties of view and update the corresponding field based on it's value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may depend on your exact `view.CommissionTypeFilterVm[0]` object (what other properties does it have) but it looks like you try to do this :

```
var com = view.CommissionTypeFilterVm[0];
for (var key in com) { // if necessary check ownProperty
   this['$'+key.charAt(0).toLowerCase()+key.slice(1)]
      .prop({checked: com[key]==1, disabled: com[key]!=1});
}
```

Comment: `this['$'+key.lowerCaseFirst()].prop({checked: com[key]==1, disabled: com[key]!=1})`, but +1

Comment: @Bergi I've never heard of lowerCaseFirst, and can't find it in the MDN. doesn't seem to work in chrome either. Am i just looking in the wrong place?

Comment: +1 Bergi, I hadn't see the first char case. I edited with a fix.

Comment: @KevinB: It's not official. You could add it to the String.prototye, but it was enough to be descriptive :-)

Comment: You need to set both the `checked` and `disabled` for each property. Right now you're just setting one or the other.

Comment: @dystroy: It seems to me that OP is setting both the `checked` and `disabled` properties whether the condition passes or fails. Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: I am getting the following error when tried ur code: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'prop': object is null or undefined

Comment: Check the spelling of your trial(s).

Answer (score 2):

```
if (view && view.CommissionTypeFilterVm && view.CommissionTypeFilterVm.length) {
    var vm = view.CommissionTypeFilterVm[0],
        props = ["CommissionType", "CommissionTrials", "OverrideType", "OverrideTrials", "BonusType", "AdjustmentType"];
    for (var i=0; i<props.length; i++) {
        var prop = props[i],
            bool = vm[prop] != 1,
            key = "$"+prop.charAt(0).toLowerCase()+prop.slice(1);
        this[key].prop({checked: !bool, disabled: bool});
    }
}
```

You could work around the ugly key manipulation if you'd named your properties respectively. You need to do so anyway as you have a typo in the trails/trials.

Comment: +1 for your remarks on my answer (I hadn't see until now you had made an answer too). For the typo, I guess it had to be fixed anyway, not reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a static map and loop over it:

```
    if (view != null && view.CommissionTypeFilterVm != null && view.CommissionTypeFilterVm.length > 0) 
{
    var mapping = [ 
        { type: 'CommisionType', ele: '$commisionType' },
        { type: 'CommissionTrials', ele: '$commissionTrails' },
        { type: 'OverrideType', ele: '$overrideType' },
        { type: 'BonusType', ele: '$BonusType' }
    ];
    var self = this;

    $.each(mapping, function() {
        if (view.CommissionTypeFilterVm[0][this.type] !==1) {
            self[this.ele].prop("checked", false).prop("disabled", true);
        } else {
            self[this.ele].prop("disabled", false).prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Could be further optimised, see @Sushanth--'s answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not efficient .. Try this

```
if (view != null) 
{
    if (view.CommissionTypeFilterVm !=null 
                    && view.CommissionTypeFilterVm.length>0)
    {
        var typeFilter = view.CommissionTypeFilterVm[0];
        var check = typeFilter.CommissionType === 0 ? true : false;
        this.$commissionType.prop({ 'checked' : !check , 'disabled' : check });
        check = typeFilter.CommissionTrials === 0 ? true : false;
        this.$commissionTrails.prop({ 'checked' : !check , 'disabled' : check });
        check = typeFilter.OverrideType === 0 ? true : false;
        this.$overrideType.prop({ 'checked' : !check , 'disabled' : check });
        check = typeFilter.OverrideTrials === 0 ? true : false;
        this.$commissionType.prop({ 'checked' : !check , 'disabled' : check });
        check = typeFilter.BonusType === 0 ? true : false;
        this.$bonusType.prop({ 'checked' : !check , 'disabled' : check });
        check = typeFilter.AdjustmentType === 0 ? true : false;
        this.$adjustmentType.prop({ 'checked' : !check , 'disabled' : check });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be further optimised, see @syazdani's answer